# SQL query to get data of MCQ question and the answer from two table

Tags: sql, database

MCQ Question and correct answer table name = **Table1**

Options for every MCQ question and options code table Name = **Table2**

## Table1

[image]

## Table2

[image]

SQL query to get data in the form of –

*Questions, All 3 options and correct option*

Comment: Which _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?  Also, have you tried writing some SQL code yourself before you posted here?

Comment: I know basic sql query and not able to think how to write query to get result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using MSSQL as database

Use `JOINS`

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fc09c600c1ef4671728565bfa0884908)

```
SELECT Q.ID, Q.Que Quetion, A.Choice Options, Op.Choice AS Answer
FROM Table1 Q JOIN Table2 A ON Q.Id= A.Id
LEFT JOIN Table2 Op ON Q.ID = Op.Id AND Q.Ans_Id = Op.Choice_Id
```

Or

```
SELECT Q.ID, Q.Que Quetion, A.Choice Options, Op.Choice AS Answer
FROM Table1 Q JOIN Table2 A ON Q.Id= A.Id
LEFT JOIN Table2 Op ON Q.ID = Op.Id AND Q.Ans_Id = Op.Choice_Id 
                   AND Op.Choice_Id = A.Choice_Id
```

**Output**

```
ID  Quetion             Options      Answer
1   Sample Question #1  (a) sasas   (a) sasas
1   Sample Question #1  (b) saewew  (a) sasas
1   Sample Question #1  (c) 4234    (a) sasas
2   Sample Question #2  (a) xxxxx   (c) sd4234
2   Sample Question #2  (b) 5855sz  (c) sd4234
2   Sample Question #2  (c) sd4234  (c) sd4234
3   Sample Question #3  (a) bbbbbb  (b) saew34
3   Sample Question #3  (b) saew34  (b) saew34
3   Sample Question #3  (c) 42d34   (b) saew34
```

Comment: both query are working for me and I use second one. Is it possible to **combine all three options** into one box  with line break between every options in **result table** to reduce number of row by 1/3 in result table.

Comment: @beginner That is something you should handle in your presentation layer, not directly in SQL.

Comment: @beginner still if you want, you can use `stuff` and `for xml path` to combine all 3 options and use `char(10)` and `char(13)` to form the new line.